# How can I test if an enum is defined or not whilst ignoring case?

Tags: c#, enums, case-sensitive

The following generic static method takes a **string** and returns an **enum**.

It nicely **ignores case** since I set the ignoreCase parameter to true.

However, I also want to **test if the enum exists**, but the enum.IsDefined method to do this doesn't seem to have an **ignoreCase** parameter.

**How can I test if the enum is defined or not and at the same ignore case?**

```
using System;

namespace TestEnum2934234
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LessonStatus lessonStatus = StringHelpers.ConvertStringToEnum<LessonStatus>("prepared");
            ReportStatus reportStatus = StringHelpers.ConvertStringToEnum<ReportStatus>("finished");

            Console.WriteLine(lessonStatus.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(reportStatus.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class StringHelpers
    {
        public static T ConvertStringToEnum<T>(string text)
        {
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), text)) //does not have ignoreCase parameter
                return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), text, true);
            else
                return default(T);
        }
    }

    public enum LessonStatus
    {
        Defined,
        Prepared,
        Practiced,
        Recorded
    }

    public enum ReportStatus
    {
        Draft,
        Revising,
        Finished
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider a default value of None for your enums. Besides being good practice, as it stands right now, if you pass a string of "Foo" for either of your enums, you get what appears to be valid values from ConvertStringToEnum.

Answer (score 44):

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Bar,
    Foo
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var containsFoo = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).Any(x => x.ToLower() == "foo");
        Console.WriteLine(containsFoo);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution!

Answer (score 33):

Along with @Darin's answer, in .NET 4.0, the Enum type now has a TryParse method:

```
MyEnum result;
Enum.TryParse("bar", true, out result);
```

The important thing to remember is that there is a fundamental difference in the behaviour of Parse vs TryParse.  Parse methods will throw exceptions.  TryParse methods will not.  This is quite important to know if you are potentially trying to parse many items.

Comment: This may return an unexpected result for string'ified numeric values.   i.e. `Enum.TryParse("01", true, out result)` will return `true` if there happens to be an enum with the value `1`.    On the other hand, Darin's answer will only match the enum names.

Comment: @BenCottrell `Enum.TryParse("01", true, out result)` will return `true` even without a value of `1` in the enum. One should be aware of this. For more robust solution one will have to use a combination of both.

Answer (score 9):

You might be able to get away with simply using `Enum.TryParse`, as others have said.

However, if you want a more robust/general conversion that allows you to convert more than just strings, then you need to also use `Enum.IsDefined`, which unfortunately, as you found, is **not** case-insensitive.

`Enum.TryParse` **is** (can be) case-insensitive. But unfortunately, it allows out-of-range ints to get through!

So the solution is to use them together (and the order is important).

I wrote an extension method that does just that. It allows conversion from string, int/int?, and any other Enum/Enum? type like so:

```cs
string value1 = "Value1";
Enum2 enum2 = value1.ParseToEnum<Enum2>();
Debug.Assert(enum2.ToString() == value1);

Enum1 enum1 = Enum1.Value1;
enum2 = enum1.ParseToEnum<Enum2>();
Debug.Assert(enum2.ToString() == enum1.ToString());

int value2 = 1;
enum2 = value2.ParseToEnum<Enum2>();
Debug.Assert(enum2.GetHashCode() == value2);
```

Here's the heart of the method. This is the conversion part that answers your question. The variable `value` is of type `object` because of the "overloads" I have that take different types as the main input (see above), but you can do this with a variable of type `string` just fine if that's all you want (obviously changing `value.ToString()` to just `value`).

```cs
if (value != null)
{
    TEnum result;
    if (Enum.TryParse(value.ToString(), true, out result))
    {
        // since an out-of-range int can be cast to TEnum, double-check that result is valid
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), result.ToString()))
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

There's a lot more to my extension method... it allows you to specify defaults, handles out-of-range ints just fine, and is fully case-insensitive. I can post more of it if anybody's interested.

Comment: The key for me was the idea of using the result of TryParse's output .ToString; thank you. Others who suggest only TryParse miss the out of range ints which can give false positive matches.

Comment: Your `Enum.IsDefined()` call in the example code is completely redundant and provides no value.

Comment: Does the comment above that line of code not explain the need for it? I put it in because I tested and found that out-of-range ints can be parsed even if the enum doesn't have a value corresponding to that int. Did you test this code at all?

Answer (score 5):

Use [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317.aspx) instead:

```
T val;

if(Enum.TryParse(text, true, out val))
    return val;
else 
    return default(T);
```

Comment: Your `else` clause is redundant. The code would do exactly the same thing written as `Enum.TryParse(text, true, out T val); return val;`

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Compact Framework 3.5, and:

```
Enum.TryParse
```

...doesn't exist. It does have:

```
Enum.IsDefined
```

..but that doesn't support the *ignoreCase* parameter.
I'd like the best of both worlds, so came up with this (as a helper method)...

```
public bool TryParse<TEnum>(string value, bool ignoreCase, ref TEnum result) where TEnum : struct
{
    bool parsed;
    try
    {
        result = (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), value, ignoreCase);
        parsed = true;
    }
    catch { }
    return parsed;
}
```

HTH

Comment: This approach fails if you pass it a string containing an integer value that doesn't appear in the enum.  Try parsing "55" as a `System.DayOfWeek` enum.

Answer (score 1):

```
    enum DaysCollection
    {
     sunday,
     Monday,
     Tuesday,
     Wednesday,
     Thursday,
     Friday,
     Saturday
    }

    public bool isDefined(string[] arr,object obj)
    {
        bool result=false;
        foreach (string enu in arr)
        {
              result = string.Compare(enu, obj.ToString(), true) == 0;
              if (result)
                  break;

        }
        return result;


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object obj = "wednesday";
        string[] arr = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DaysCollection)).ToArray();

        isDefined(arr,obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make text same case as enum string:

```
enum FileExts
{
  jpg,
  pdf
}

if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), text.tolower())) //does not have ignoreCase parameter
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), text, true);
else
    return default(T);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar concern and used a combination of both the `.Enum.TryPase` (with the case-insensitive flag set as `true`) and `Enum.IsDefined`. Consider the following as a simplification to your helper class:

```
public static class StringHelpers
{
    public static T ConvertStringToEnum<T>(string text)
    {
        T result;
        return Enum.TryParse(text, true, out result)
            && Enum.IsDefined(result.ToString())
                ? result
                : default(T);
    }
}
```

And while we're at it, since the helper class is static and the method is static - we could make this an extension method on `string`.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static TEnum ToEnum<TEnum>(this string text)
        where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible 
    {
        TEnum result = default(TEnum);
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) 
            && Enum.TryParse(text, true, out result)
            && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), result.ToString())
                ? result
                : default(TEnum);
    }
}
```

Here, I created a [<kbd>`.NET Fiddle`</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BydWHh) that clearly demonstrates this.

Comment: This approach fails if you pass it a string containing an integer value that doesn't appear in the enum. Using your fiddle example, try calling `Console.WriteLine("55".ToEnum<ReportStatus>());`.

Answer (score 1):

First use `Enum.TryParse` method to get an object of type `T`, then pass that object to `Enum.IsDefined` method:

```
private static T ConvertStringToEnum<T>(string stringValue) where T : struct
{
    if (System.Enum.TryParse(stringValue, out T result))
    {
        if (System.Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), result) || result.ToString().Contains(","))
            return result;

        throw new System.Exception($"{stringValue} is not an underlying value of the {typeof(T).FullName} enumeration.");
    }

    throw new System.Exception($"{stringValue} is not a member of the {typeof(T).FullName} enumeration.");
}
```

Comment: Except this does not ignore case.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T ConvertStringToEnum<T>(string text)
{
    T returnVal;
    try
    {
        returnVal = (T) Enum.Parse( typeof(T), text, true );
    }
    catch( ArgumentException )
    {
        returnVal = default(T);
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```